# How to align button text when increasing font size in settings

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

When creating a `Button` with text in Xamarin Forms and increasing the font size in the mobile settings, the text does not fit on the `Button`. Is there a way to adjust the size of the text to the `Button`?

Button code:

```html
<Button
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color1gray}"
                        BorderRadius="5"
                        HeightRequest="30"
                        Text="Cancelar"
                        WidthRequest="150" />
```

That's how the `Button` looks with default font size:

[image]

That's how the `Button` looks with max font size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that height adjustment cannot be made automatically because you set "
HeightRequest=50". You can easily resolve the problem with deleting HeightRequest=50 from your button.

[image]

It is better to use Grid to adjust the height according to the screensize.
Example:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid Grid.Row="0">
   </Grid>

   <Button Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color1gray}"
                        BorderRadius="5"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="Cancelar" />
</Grid>
```